# Figuring out local time on user's machine in UTC?

Tags: java, android

I need to set an alarm on a user's phone. This is an android function, and the alarm takes the time to fire in System.currentTimeMillis() format. I want to set the alarm at 7pm on the user's phone, but I don't know what timezone the user has their phone set to.

How can I figure out what the equivalent time at 7pm for the current day is in UTC (currentTimeMillis()) ?

Thanks

Comment: Does this function run on the user's phone? If so, what is the OS run by the phone?

Comment: Yes it runs on the user's phone. It is android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); // returns current time in user's default TimeZone
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 19);
long time = cal.getTime().getTime();
```

Comment: As a note, all instances of java.util.Date are in UTC.  However, when you try to format them (ie via SimpleDateFormat or the .toString() method), it uses either the system default timezone, or some other timezone which you set either by passing the DateFormatter a Locale in the constructor or a Timezone object (via a setter).  If you want to work with dates properly, i'd highly recommend you google "joda-time", as it's much more useable than anything provided in the JDK.